# How to test a dynamic substring variable in a conditional in shellscript?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, variables, dynamic

This code check if the last 4 characters of the variable $1 correspond to the string in variable $2 anticipated by a dot.

```
    if [ "${1: -4}" == ".$2" ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi

// true with $1 = example.doc and $2 = doc
// false with $1 = example.docx and $2 = doc
```

how can I replace the hardcoded 4 with the following variable $CHECKER_EXTENSION calculated like this?

```
    LENGTH_EXTENSION=${#2}
    CHECKER_EXTENSION=$(( LENGTH_EXTENSION + 1 ))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: If the part you wish to get is always behind a dot (`.`) you may use: `${url##*.}` instead of counting the number of chars you need to remove

Comment: @0stone0: That's a good point; but note that it will give the wrong result if `$2` contains a dot (if that's possible).

Comment: @Cyrus I needed to know how to replace the hardcoded 4 with a variable, the goal is to check if a filename and a given extension are the same, but that was not the question. I use the dot as an extra check in the filename.

Comment: Replace `4` with `$variable`.

Comment: Well, complete answers are already there, this is a bit "poor" and not working in my example, simple as you explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset is interpreted as an arithmetic expression (the same syntax as inside `$(( ... ))`), so you can write:

```
    if [ "${1: -CHECKER_EXTENSION}" == ".$2" ]; then
```

You can even eliminate the CHECKER_EXTENSION variable and write:

```
    if [ "${1: -(${#2} + 1)}" == ".$2" ]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to strip the leading characters from `$1`, since bash's `[[ ]]` can do wildard-style pattern matching:

```
if [[ "$1" = *".$2" ]]; then
    ...
```

Note that you *must* use `[[ ]]`, and not `[ ]`, to get pattern-matching rather than simple string equality testing. Also, having the `*` unquoted but `.$2` in quotes means the `*` will be treated as a wildcard, but `$2` will be matched literally even if it contains wildcardish characters. If you want `$2` to also be treated as a pattern (e.g. you could use `[Jj][Pp][Gg]` to match "jpg" and "JPG" and combinations), leave off the quotes:

```
if [[ "$1" = *.$2 ]]; then
```

Oh, and the quotes around `$1` don't matter in this particular situation; but I tend to double-quote variables unless there's a specific reason not to.

Comment: +1. This is one of those cases where what the OP is asking for isn't really what the OP should use in his/her specific situation. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use it like this:

```
myfunc() {
   local num_ext=$(( ${#2} + 1 ))

   [[ "${1: -$num_ext}" = ".$2" ]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your execution environment meets the following criteria, you can choose a more concise method.

- The requirement is to check if the extension is as expected
- I'm using Bash

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ${1##*.} == "${2}" ]]; then
  echo "same"
else
  echo "not same"
fi
```

Execute test.

```sh
# test case 1
$ ./sample.sh test.txt txt
same

# test case 2
$ ./sample.sh test.exe txt
not same

# test case 3
$ ./sample.sh test.exe.txt txt
same

# test case 4
$ ./sample.sh test.txt.exe txt
not same

# test case 5
$ ./sample.sh test.txt.exe exe
same
```